# Parsing string with a different character

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I parse this string "451:45" to a number? What I want to get is "451.45" as number.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace the colon with a dot and just call `parseFloat()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace the colon [:] with the dot [.] by using `replace` method of JS as -

   ```
   '451.45'.replace(":", ".");
   ```
2. Now, we have desired string but as we need number so just parse it into Float by using `parseFloat` as -

   ```
   parseFloat('451.45');
   ```

   Please find the complete code as -

   ```
   let str = '451:45';
   str = str.replace(":", ".");
   str = parseFloat(str);
   ```

Let me know in comments if you need any help further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so:
`console.log(+"451:45".replace(':', '.'));`
i.E:

```js
private parseMyNumber(n: string): number{
  return +n.replace(':', '.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular and typescrip I use this code

```
const stringNumber = '451:45';
console.log(Number(str.replace(":", ".")));
```

I don't know if you have it inside a function in that case would be something like this

```
stringReplaceToNumber(string: string) {
return Number(string.replace(":", "."))
}
```